# circular dependency (class on typedef, typedef on class), forward declaration gives ambigous call?

Tags: c++

Im trying to find an acceptable solution to the following circular dependency :

```
template<typename T>
struct Y {
  void f(T&) {}
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct X : public Y<T>, public Y<U> {};

struct A;
struct B;
typedef X<A,B> Z;

struct A {
  void g(Z& z) {
    z.f(*this);
  }
};

struct B {
  void g(Z& z) {
    z.f(*this);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Z z;
  A a;
  B b;
  a.g(z);
  b.g(z);
}
```

In the code Z depends on A and B, and A/B depend on Z. A/B cannot be converted to template class definitions. When I forward declare A and B (as shown) then I get an ambigous call, presumably because the typedef instantiates X with incomplete types?

Of course I can simply define X as the following and everything works :

```
struct A;
struct B;

struct X {
  void f(A&) {}
  void f(B&) {}
};

typedef X Z;

struct A {
  void g(Z& z) {
    z.f(*this);
  }
};

struct B {
  void g(Z& z) {
    z.f(*this);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Z z;
  A a;
  B b;
  a.g(z);
  b.g(z);
}
```

... but how to define Z as a typedef when X is a template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not due to the incomplete types. The member function definition won't be instantiated until that member is used. The declaration of the members *will* be, but the type being incomplete won't make a declaration ill-formed. Not to mention, you don't use the type in any way that would be problematic on accout of it being incomplete.

It's just an artefact of the name lookup rules. You can provide a using declaration to pull those `f` members into `X`:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct X : public Y<T>, public Y<U> {
    using Y<T>::f;
    using Y<U>::f;
};
```

That resolves the ambiguity.

Comment: Great... I think I can accept this as the answer. As an extension I'd like to specify X as a variadic template. However this means I need pack expansions for using declarations, which is not standard in C++11, it seems (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0195r2.html)

Comment: @the4thamigo_uk - It is not, I'm afraid. That would require C++17. Though some clever re-writing should make a "recursive" using declaration work.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with circular dependencies, but with multiple inheritance. The clang error is pretty clear: "error: member 'f' found in multiple base classes of different types".

One solution is to disambiguate which `f` you mean: is the one inherited from `Y<T>` or the one inherited from `Y<U>`:

```
z.Y<A>::f(*this);

z.Y<B>::f(*this);
```

Comment: yes, this is ok, and I thought about this, but I don't really want to change the call to Z::f in the g() function implementations

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I think is reasonable, but a little ugly is :

```
template<typename T>
struct Y {
  void f(T&) {}
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct X : public Y<T>, public Y<U> {
  template<typename V>
  void f(V& v) {
    this->Y<V>::f(v);
  }
};

struct A;
struct B;
typedef X<A,B> Z;

struct A {
  void g(Z& z) {
    z.f(*this);
  }
};

struct B {
  void g(Z& z) {
    z.f(*this);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Z z;
  A a;
  B b;
  a.g(z);
  b.g(z);
}
```